Input and clip WCS raster in QGIS model designer
I am working with an automatisation tool in the QGIS model designer tool and in that tool I want to input a DEM from a WCS connection. The DEM represents a much larger area than needed so I planned to clip the extent and export to raster file, similar what you can do manually in the tool Export layer to file.
How can I execute this in the model designer and is it possible to give authentication credentials as well?
